# How to append all sheets in multiple Excel files into One Excel file (not consolidating or combining them into one sheet)

Tags: python, pandas

I want to combine multiple Excel files/sheets into one Excel file with multiple sheets without changing any formatting. Basically, it is to append all sheets in multiple Excel files into One Excel file with multiple sheets.

For example,
File1 with Sheet1
File2 with Sheet2, Sheet3
File3 with Sheet4, Sheet5

Outcome would be File0 with Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3, Sheet4, Sheet5 (as one Excel file).

Here is a code:

```
from pandas import ExcelWriter 
import glob
import os
import pandas as pd

writer = ExcelWriter("File0.xlsx")
for filename in glob.glob("'File*.xlsx"):
    excel_file = pd.ExcelFile(filename)
    #(_, f_name) = os.path.split(filename)
    #(f_short_name, _) = os.path.splitext(f_name)
    for sheet_name in excel_file.sheet_names:
        df_excel = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name)
        df_excel.to_excel(writer, sheet_name, index=False)
writer.save()
```

The code works, but it re-writes the sheets. So I am losing all formats. Is there another way to append all sheets into one Excel file without consolidating them or losing the formatting?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to load all sheets into a list put them in a sheet with different names!

```
from pandas import ExcelWriter 
import glob
import os
import pandas as pd


list_of_sheets = []
for filename in glob.glob("'File*.xlsx"):
    excel_file = pd.ExcelFile(filename)
    list_of_sheets.append(excel_file)

# now add them as different sheets in same excel file
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('multiple.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
for i in range(0, len(list_of_sheets)):
    list_of_sheets[i].to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet{}'.format(i))
writer.save()

# in this way, it will be one sheet called multiple.xlsx where each sheet name will be named like sheet1, sheet2... and so on!
#Please accept and upvote the answer if it works, or comment if you have a doubt or error!
```

Comment: Hi Tejas, thank you for sharing, but it did not work. It shows 'Sheet1' with empty content. Actually, what I want to do is to append all sheets from multiple Excel files into One Excel file. Sheet names vary as well. In this case, do I list all sheet names "list_of_sheets"? Thank you.